# Consigure Azure AD with Okta

Tags: azure, active-directory, okta

I am trying to set up my application with okta as IDP and delegated access as an azure ad. So that he can access MSI enabled azure services.

Answer (score 0):

MSI enabled Azure Services use Azure AD behind the scene. In this case you should connect an app with Azure AD directly. MSI is our Managed Identity service.

I am not sure why you cant use Azure AD directly here instead of OKTA?

Comment: Its client requirement. They want to use Ocka as IDP and deploy the app in azure. Also want to keep user azure key vault. Please let me know if this is possible. If yes then how Okta IDP claims will be used to access Azure services.